# Stuck on the beginning and end of a "slideshow" created in P5

Tags: processing, p5.js

Relatively new to programming and I am creating a short program for a class and almost have everything the way I am happy with except two things. I am sure it is just my brain keeping me from seeing the something obvious but I am stuck/blocked.

When you run the program, there should be a background image (random) that displays behind the text but my background (safety) color is the only thing showing. They came thing is happening at the end and the final text phrase is not showing (as well as one of the images).

I am sure it is within the arrays for the text and images being called but I tried to tweak the for loops and got goofy results. I am getting an error message that I am sure is related to the arrays start and end point.

If I get an error when being graded, I will have it returned to correct of have to take an incomplete on the assignment. I was hoping someone could look at it and tell me what I should do the get the image and the beginning and the image/text at the end to display w/o getting any errors when run. I know I am very close... :(

Here is a link to my project: https://editor.p5js.org/Rico2022/sketches/bOLM0PeET

Comment: Please share a [mcve] in the question itself rather than a link, which tends to rot over time. You can use the stack snippet to make a runnable p5 example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Function calls

```js
doBackground();
doCoverage();
doImage();
doText();
```

should always be called together, that is even the first time, at `setup`. For efficiency, you'd better define a new function that calls the four of them and use that function both in `setup` and `mousePressed`

2. The condition should be `if (counter < words.length)` and the
   function `doText` should not be called on the `else` branch
3. You're missing an item in `wordSizes` (they are only 13), that's one reason the last text is not shown.
4. You have duplicated code: 3 lines after `var selectedPic =`  are repeated immediately after.

---

If you're not already doing it, you should learn to use [`console.log`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/console/log) to get the errors (debug) your code - it displays the argument in the console below the editor so you can trace what happens at each stage in the program.

For instance, a `console.log(counter, wordSizes[counter])` inserted (temporarily!) as the first line in `doText` allowed me to see that you miss a value in `wordSizes`.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had work/school/work, so I couldn't get back to this as soon as I wanted. I thank you! You were able to help me figure it out and get my assignment turned in by the deadline. I ended up fixing the array lendth and adding a counter++ to one function and a count = 0 to te end and it works pretty well for a newbie! I am a graphic designer first and then a complete novice at coding. I got the prof to give me a two day extension to get what I got done doen before I reached out for help. I was down to the wire.  I got the assignment turned in on time. Thank you again!!